# jQuery UI theme for Zurb Foundation?

Tags: jquery-ui, zurb-foundation

I have an excellent jquery-ui based application that I'd like to give the fresh looks of Foundation. Most important part I'm missing is the support properly styled dialogs which currently have the jquery looks.
Is there anything like a foundation-styled jQuery UI theme or project setup to develop one?

Comment: i highly doubt it. you just have to style each piece of thing manually or use bootstrap/jquery-ui https://github.com/jquery-ui-bootstrap/jquery-ui-bootstrap/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My company has used http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ to create the themes for our clients.

We had a client request a theme that matched the foundation default styling so we created it and uploaded it to out github. Below you can download the style sheets.

https://github.com/cwdgservices/jQuery-UI-Style-for-Zurb-Foundation

Comment: Thank you very much, dear sir. :)